# Porque No me muestra todos los <div> que contiene imagen al cargar la pagina

Tags: php, html

actualmente estoy realizando un codigo en una pagina (ejemplo.php) el cual ingreso logeandome. el punto es que cuando cargo la pagina me sale la imagen de arriba, pero no la imagen de abajo... algo asi:

esta es la imgen de arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aca abajo deberia salir otra imagen, pero sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo curioso es que cuando achico la pantalla(ctrl+(roller de mouse)) a un 80% si muestra la imagen, de la sgte manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces resulta que cuando cuando actualizo la pagina, y lo mantengo en su 80%, no sale la 2da imagen, y de nuevo tengo que achicar o agrandar la pagina para que salga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando disminuyo a 50% o menos, si sale, y al cargar la pagina tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo ejemplo.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 #$codigo=$_SESSION["codigo"];

  if (!isset($_SESSION["codigo"])) {
    echo '<script> alert("Ud no ha iniciado sesión. Favor de loguearse") 
</script>';
    echo '<script> window.location="../redesdeacceso_/"; </script>';
 }else{

    if (isset($_SESSION['codigo'])) {
        $codigo=$_SESSION['codigo'];
        include("config/conexion.php");
        $con->query("UPDATE personal SET visita_online='1' WHERE codigo='".$codigo."' ");
    }


$con->query("UPDATE personal SET visita_online='1' WHERE codigo=".$codigo." ");
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600;url=../redesdeacceso_/" />';


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Portal </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">

<!-- Flexslider  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">

<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<!-- Flaticons  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">

<!-- Theme style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- FOR IE9 below -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- actualizar cada 10 minutos la hoja     <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=../redesdeacceso_/' />     -->   


    <style type="text/css">
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,50,0.5);/*rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: rgba(247,243,242,0.5);/*-webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
</style>




</head>
<body>

<!-- Form para modal -->

<form action="cambio_clave.php" method="POST">
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" >
        <div class="container" style="padding:0px;width: 420px">


            <a href="#Cerrar" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <div class="panel-heading" style="background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);">
            <center><h2>Camvio de Clave <img src="images/claro.png" width="70" height="70"></h2></center>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body" style="clear:both">
            <img src="images/clave.png" width="40" height="40">
            <input class="password"  type="text" id="password1" value="" name="password1" style="width: 250px; height: 40px;border-radius: 5px;background: #ffff99;font-size:14px;" placeholder="Ingrese password antiguo" autocomplete="new-password">


            <br><br>
            <img src="images/clave.png" width="40" height="40">
            <input class="password"  type="text" id="password2" value="" name="password2" style="width: 250px; height: 40px;border-radius: 5px;background: #ffff99;font-size:14px;" placeholder="Ingrese password nuevo" autocomplete="new-password">


            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="registrar">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="colorlib-loader"></div>

<div id="page">
    <nav class="colorlib-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="upper-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <p>Gerencia de Operaciones y Calidad Serv Campo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <p><img src="images/personal.svg" width="20" height="20"> Bienvenido(a), <?php echo $_SESSION["nombre_personal"]; ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-push-2 text-right">
                        <p class="btn-apply"><a href="http://eclaro/nosotros/Home.aspx" target="_blank">Nuestra Visión y Misión</a></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-push-2 text-right">
                        <p class="btn-apply"><a href="../redesdeacceso_/">Salir</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div id="colorlib-logo"><a href="http://eclaro/home.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo_eclaro.png"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 text-right menu-1">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Aplicaciones">Aplicaciones</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="http://172.16.121.4:8082/arsys/shared/login.jsp?/arsys/forms/limnwkvipv02/SHR%3ALandingConsole/Default+Administrator+View/?cacheid=82101867" target="_blank">Remedy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://172.19.4.190/cgi-bin/planning/test/site.php" target="_blank">LBS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://limnintexv04/AceptacionProyectos/Solicitud/Forms/AllItems.aspx" target="_blank">ATPs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://172.19.112.62/central_login/index.php?action=remoteAuthenticacion&service=http://172.19.112.62/generador/&apiKey=fukL8Cw5456D4YkL0009uI7iK1W17Nqoi" target="_blank">Reportes Direcc.</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://172.19.84.74/GMyD/FormularioPrincipal/Principal.aspx" target="_blank">GMyD</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://172.19.112.134:8080/smartflex/login" target="_blank">Smart Flex</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://172.16.102.103/packetloss" target="_blank">PacketLoss</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://172.19.112.62/generador" target="_blank">PacketLoss G.</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://172.17.31.5:31943/login.action?_=1534872216908" target="_blank">NetEco</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://10.244.22.143:9001/portal-field/" target="_blank">Pext Report</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://172.19.112.62/central_login/index.php?action=remoteAuthenticacion&service=http://172.19.112.62/generador/project/name/Horarios-Personal-en-Remedy&apiKey=fukL8Cw5456D4YkL0009uI7iK1W17Nqoi" target="_blank">Horario Turnos</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Accesos">Accesos</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <?php

                                    if($_SESSION['perfil']!="0"){
                                    echo "<li><a href='direccion_site'>Direccion Sites</a></li>";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo '<li><a href="mailto:lalcocer@claro.com.pe?cc=PersonalRedesdeAccesoLima@claro.com.pe&subject=Accesos a Portal Claro (Gerencia de Operaciones y Calidad Serv Campo)&body=Estimados,%0DSe requiere la autorización al link: Direcciones de Sites.%0D%0DSaludos">Ver Direccion</a></li>';

                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Kpis">KPIs</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="KPIs">INC & CRQ</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Entidades">Entidades</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="https://bcpzonasegurabeta.viabcp.com/#/iniciar-sesion" target="_blank"><img src="images/bcp.png" width="50" height="15"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.scotiabank.com.pe/Personas/Default" target="_blank"><img src="images/scotiabank.png" width="80" height="20"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.sunat.gob.pe/" target="_blank">www.sunat.gob.pe</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.reniec.gob.pe/portal/intro.htm" target="_blank">www.reniec.gob.pe</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Intranet">Intranet</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="http://eclaro/home.aspx" target="_blank">E-Claro</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://eclaro/SitePages/Tienda%20Virtual.aspx" target="_blank">Tienda <img src="images/tienda.svg" width="20" height="30"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://eclaro/desarrolloprofesional/carrerasclaro/Home.aspx" target="_blank">Carreras <img src="images/carreras.svg" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://intranetwebapp/aplicaciones/inicio.aspx" target="_blank">Portal Aplic.</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Otros">Otros</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">www. <img src="images/google.png" width="40" height="15"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.invertexto.com/comparar-textos" target="_blank">Comparar text</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Password">Password</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li>
                                        <!-- llama a ventana modal -->
                                        <a href="#openModal">Cambiar pass <img src="images/password.svg" width="15" height="15"></a>
                                        <!-- fin -->

                                    </li>


                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Administrador">Administrador</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Usuarios <img src="images/personal.svg" width="40" height="15"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.invertexto.com/comparar-textos" target="_blank">Subir excel</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#Online">Online</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <?php

                                    $datos=$con->query("SELECT * FROM personal WHERE visita_online='1' ");


                                    while ($r=$datos->fetch_array()) {

                                        echo '<li><a><img src="images/personal/'.$r["codigo"].'.jpg" width="25" height="30">'.' '.$r["nombre_personal"].' '.substr($r["apellido"],0,1).'. '.'</a></li>';

                                    }
                                    ?>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!--<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>-->

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <aside id="colorlib-hero">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_1.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-1 slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <h2>Nuestros Valores</h2>
                                    <h1>1. Honestidad</h1>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_5.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-1 slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <h2>Nuestros Valores</h2>
                                    <h1>2. Manos en la operación</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-1 slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <h2>Nuestros Valores</h2>
                                    <h1>3. Actitud de Servicio</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_4.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-1 slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <h2>Nuestros Valores</h2>
                                    <h1>4. Orden y Disciplina</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!--<li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-1 slider-text">
                            <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <h2>Nuestros Valores</h2>
                                    <h1>5. Eficiencia</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>-->    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>




    <div id="colorlib-counter" class="colorlib-counters">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="about-desc">
                    <div class="about-img-1 animate-box" style="background-image: url(images/about-img-2.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="about-img-2 animate-box" style="background-image: url(images/about-img-1.jpg);"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 colorlib-heading animate-box">
                        <h1 class="heading-big">Quienes somos</h1>
                        <h2>Quienes somos</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 animate-box">
                        <p><strong>Claro Perú opera en el país desde el 10 de agosto de 2005.</strong></p>
                        <p>Claro Perú es subsidiaria de América Móvil, S.A.B. de C.V. el proveedor líder de servicios de telecomunicaciones móviles en Latinoamérica con operaciones en 25 países de América y Europa, y 363 millones de líneas de accesos.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate-box">
                        <div class="counter-entry">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <span class="colorlib-counter js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="25" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50"></span>
                                <span class="colorlib-counter-label">Paises</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate-box">
                        <div class="counter-entry">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <span class="colorlib-counter js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="4695" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50"></span>
                                <span class="colorlib-counter-label">Sites en Peru</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate-box">
                        <div class="counter-entry">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <span class="colorlib-counter js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="2038" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50"></span>
                                <span class="colorlib-counter-label">Sites en Lima</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 animate-box">
                        <div class="counter-entry">
                            <div class="desc">
                                <span class="colorlib-counter js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="90" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50"></span>
                                <span class="colorlib-counter-label">POP</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>







<div class="gototop js-top">
    <a href="#" class="js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up2"></i></a>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Waypoints -->
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<!-- Stellar Parallax -->
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Flexslider -->
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<!-- Owl carousel -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
<!-- Counters -->
<script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<!-- Main -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

entonces... que estaria haciendo que no me muestren los dos DIV al momento de cargar la pagina??

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas tardes, me ha pasado lo que dices y puede pasar por varios motivos, lo primero que se me ocurre es que quizás el **div** que contiene esas imágenes no esta tomando el atributo height por algún motivo, trata de setearle el height (puedes setearle un height como 1000px para estirarlo bien) a ese div y colorearlo indicandole una propiedad por css como `div{border:1px solid red}`, con esta propiedad veras el div y por allí puede ver como se esta comportando cuando cargas la pagina y cuando la rederizas a una menor resolución. Muy probablemente la capa tiene una propiedad css o esta heredando una propiedad css que hace que su área visible sea proporcional a su height.

Al final lo que te quiero transmitir es que el div o elemento que contiene la imagen que no se te muestra si esta alli realmente pero quizas hay otro atributo css que te lo esta afectando, por eso prueba primero seteandole el height y coloreandole un borde para que puedas visualizar bien su comportamiento, quizás el div o el contenedor de dichas imágenes su área visible es menor que su contenido total, es decir su area visible es menor que lo que puede mostrar, en la mayoría de los casos es un atributo **overflow:hidden** el que hace ese efecto. Nos cuentas como te fue.